# Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject because of a DATETIME data

Tags: php, android, mysql, datetime, android-volley

I've been struggling for a while trying to insert data into MySQL database successfuly (using Volley), well this is not the problem because data are inserted, but I keep having this error  **W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value < br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject** or an JSONEception, this error is stopping from doing anything else, if I add more code the UI freezes, I tried to remove the date code from my php file and everything went fine only the datetime value isn't the one I'm looking for,When I added back and it shows me the error again.
This is my code :

```
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener1 = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                                        try {
                                                                            JSONObject jsonResponse1 = new JSONObject(response);
                                                                            boolean success = jsonResponse1.getBoolean("success");
                                                                            if (success) {


                                                                                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                                                            } else {
                                                                                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "INSERTION FAILED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                                                            }


                                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "EXCEPTION",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                        }


                                                                    }
                                                                };




                                                                SendBookingRequest bookingRequest = new SendBookingRequest(idd,em,Adresse_source,duree,dist, responseListener1);
                                                                RequestQueue queue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(MapActivity.this);
                                                                queue1.add(bookingRequest);
```

And here is my php file **SendBookingRequest**

```
<?php
require("password.php");
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXXXX", "XXXXX", "XXXXX");

$driver_id = $_POST["driver_id"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$adresse_source = $_POST["adresse_source"];
$duree = $_POST["duree"];
$distance = $_POST["distance"];
$response = array();
$dt_obj = new DateTime($response['send_moment'], new 
DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')); 
$dt_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London')); 
$send_time = $dt_obj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
   echo $send_time;
 function AddRequest() {
    global $connect, $driver_id, $email, $adresse_source, $duree, $distance, $send_time ; 
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO demande (driver_id, pass_id, adresse_source, duree, distance, send_moment) VALUES (?, (SELECT user_id FROM passager WHERE email = ?),?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "issdis", $driver_id, $email, $adresse_source, $duree, $distance, $send_time); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
}


    $response["success"] = false;  

    AddRequest();
    $response["success"] = true;  


echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: and what about awkward idea of showing the sample of that data?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what do you mean ?

Comment: show the string you are trying to parse that causes the problem you are facing

Comment: How can I get it !!, sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: by logging? setting breakpoint and running with debugger?

Comment: I thing I got it, this is it : <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: send_moment in <b>/storage/h3/744/754744/public_html/SendBookingReq.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
2017-04-24 07:40:55{"success":true}

Comment: in fact, getting this data should be first thing you to do. Not posting on SO :)

Comment: I replaced it with "NOW" and it's working fine,thank you very much

Comment: This is not correct approach. If your backend returns JSON and there's date field then you should not return "NOW" as this is not a date. Better way is to return i.e. `null` and then you code that inserts checks for `null` and replaces it with `NOW()`, or you return no date at all and lack of it is again detected and fallback to `NOW()` is in your insert script.

Comment: Sir, the only reason that got me to insert date is that the system's time zone isn't the same with mine, I tried not to return a date at all and instead change the default time zone but I couldn't do it.

Comment: I am not questioning date inserting as such, but only point to **how** you do that. `NOW` is not a date. It may be better to have the logic reworked a bit. But that's your project so I can only suggest.

Comment: You are right sir, although the insertion worked fine, I couldn't do anything else afterward

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to put `header('Content-type: application/json');` line above of `echo json_encode($response);` in php code

Comment: I'll add it. As I discuss with Marcin Orlowski I found out that the source of the error was the indefined index send_moment